# After upgrade to Rails 5, app no longer receiving requests

Tags: ruby, puma, ruby-on-rails-5

I updated one of my apps to Rails 5 and upgraded the Ruby version to 2.3.1 as well.  The app already used Puma prior to the Rails 5 upgrade as well and was deployed on a Digital Ocean droplet.

When I start `rails server` locally, I get the normal output in my Rails log, which I've copied below.

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[14669] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[14669] * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
[14669] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[14669] * Environment: development
[14669] * Process workers: 2
[14669] * Preloading application
[14669] * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
[14669] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[14669] - Worker 1 (pid: 14684) booted, phase: 0
[14669] - Worker 0 (pid: 14683) booted, phase: 0
```

Everything looks normal to me.  When I visit localhost:3000, the browser has a pending request that is pending indefinitely.  There is no further activity in the Rails log acknowledging that any request is being received.

Has anyone encountered this type of issue, or know of any potential causes for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved this issue, and confirmed by @marvindanig who was experiencing the same issue, that the 'tmp' folder needed to be cleared.  There is a rake task in rails to do so...

```
rake tmp:clear
```