# Rails 5 unicorn server starts but not able to receive requests in dev mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, ruby-on-rails-5

I upgraded from rails 4.2.6 to rails 5 for a working app on unicorn. It has the following `config/development.rb`:

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false

  config.consider_all_requests_local = false

  config.auto_flushing = true

  config.log_level = :debug

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.quiet = true

  config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

  # config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true

end
```

When I start the unicorn server, I get no response from the server and no logs are shown on the console except this.:

```
 Welcome | Marvin Danig $ unicorn
I, [2016-08-10T15:02:56.586132 #79960]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=9
I, [2016-08-10T15:02:56.586277 #79960]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2016-08-10T15:02:56.587245 #79960]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2016-08-10T15:02:56.588312 #79973]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=79973
I, [2016-08-10T15:02:56.588762 #79973]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from require at /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86)
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from require at /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86)
I, [2016-08-10T15:03:05.343468 #79973]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
E, [2016-08-10T15:04:06.607650 #79960] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:79973 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2016-08-10T15:04:06.623636 #79960] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 79973 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
I, [2016-08-10T15:04:06.623801 #79960]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2016-08-10T15:04:06.625377 #79992]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=79992
I, [2016-08-10T15:04:06.625803 #79992]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from require at /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86)
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from require at /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86)
```

What's wrong?

---

I tried starting the app with `puma` as well in place of unicorn and still get the same issue. It has also been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428736/after-upgrade-to-rails-5-app-no-longer-receiving-requests).

Comment: The issue you referred to has been solved. Can you solve yours by following the same steps?